# Computed property on model is null after save

Tags: ember.js

I have the following model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  visibility: DS.attr('string'),

  visible: Ember.computed('visibility', function() {
    get() {
      return this.get('visibility') === 'visible';
    },

    set(key, value) {
      if(value) {
        this.set('visibility', 'visible');
      } else {
        this.set('visibility', 'hidden');
      }
    }
});
```

Then, in a template, I have a checkbox bound to the `visible` computed property:

```
{{input type="checkbox" checked=model.visible}}
```

It all works great, except when I save the model. After saving the model, `model.get('visible')` returns null. I'm not sure what's happening, but it seems the model is not consulting my computed property, as it can only possibly return true or false.

I am using Ember Data with the ActiveModelSerializer. Ember v1.13.3.

Comment: Please include the code where you save your model. Also any adapters / serializers for this model.

Comment: @Gaurav: I think I figured it out. I was calling `window.history.back` after saving the model, which was causing the model to get out of sync. Refactoring now to use a route transition to go back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

After save, I was popping the state to go back to the previous route by calling `window.history.back();`. I think this was somehow causing the model state to be out of sync. Not sure if this should be considered a bug?